# Como puedo poner en una columna, en Oracle SQL, el mismo valor unas 20 en cada fila de la columna? Y de una columna de otra tabla?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Es decir, quiero que una columna contenga el mismo valor unas determinadas veces, en este caso 20, en una columna nueva.

EJEMPLO:

**NOMBRE**

JUAN

JUAN

JUAN

JUAN

...

JUAN

Y también quiero hacer lo mismo pero de otra tabla ya existente con datos y pasarlos a una tabla nueva y repetir los datos una determinada cantidad de veces.

Comment: as intendado usar pl/sql y un for??

Comment: No... soy nuevo en esto de Oracle SQL y no se como hacer eso

Comment: tutorial? youtube? udemy? platzi? codigofasilito?